# Keeping secret information secret

Tags: java, security

So, I'm writing a password verification thingy, loading username and passwords from a database, but I can't figure out how to keep the database username and password out of the code.

```
String user = "username";//database username, not username to verify
String password = "password";//my password, not users password to check
String url = "jdbc:mysql://databaseurl:3306/table"; 
//i want this hidden somehow
```

I could load it from a file, but then people could just read the file.

Obviously I don't want people gaining access to the database and reading secret information. How should I go about doing this?

EDIT: What I'm asking, is, how can I secure **MY** *database* credentials. Other people should not have access to the *database*

You could, for instance, decompile the jar and read the above lines, and access my database using my credentials. (using a program such as jd-gui)

Comment: How will people have access to your code? Are you sharing it through an online community or just by them making use of the program?

Comment: The problem is you could decompile the jar, and read the database username and password, access the database and change whatever you want. I do not want this. 

I'm going to edit to clarify.

Comment: I suggest removing the misleading part in your question about "password verification thingy" as many bogus answers will pop up.

Comment: The best approach is to design a layer within your database-hosting server that allows your application to connect and retrieve data safely.  The database login information would be stored only on the server, keeping it safe from prying eyes. For example, a PHP script could be designed to query for verification, and the Java application would then only need to send the user's login credentials over the network, rather than the credentials to the entire database.

Comment: I second what Vulcan says. You could also add some algebraic check on the server side to validate where the login credentials are coming from. Simple examples of this are using a PHP (or other) script to increment every password and username character by a value x, such that the password/username you use in the app is a linear variation of the actual one.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I don't seem to understand clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Use password encryption.
If you application runs inside J2EE container, use standart tools

[Look at sample for Jboss container](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Encrypting_Data_Source_Passwords.html)

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch I am not the downvoter, but it does not solve the problem either, just makes it a little bit harder to get the password.

Comment: I originally downvoted this answer because simply encrypting the password is completely useless beyond deterring the least motivated potential hackers.  If the answer is referring to setting up a web service via J2EE in order to keep the database credentials on the server, far more detail needs to be added in order to make this answer useful.

Comment: I am not a security expert but what popalka suggests is definetely one of the security guidelines proposed by experts. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to give the user direct access to the database, why not just make the username/password you're passing to the database the user's actual username/database?

Typically in secure systems the database is not directly exposed to the user. The user passes a query to some system which then performs authentication and then if passes passes the query to the database.

In other words, if you're relying on the obscuring of the database login credentials as the obstruction to accessing the database, you're relying on the client to authenticate itself with respect to actually querying the database, which is a bad, bad idea. As soon as your database's login credentials are compromised, your whole security scheme has now failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep database details in a

> property file/database

. It is a kind of one layer of abstraction. And in that property file/database, you give some different keys so that at the time of accessing database, take the keys/columns from property file/database and construct url information.

Comment: Having access to the WAR will lead to that property file as well.

Comment: Keeping the credentials separate from the program allows at least easy change of the password in regular intervals. So it is better than to embed it into the code. I would also keep it outside of the WAR.

Comment: If you want to keep off the application, then I would suggest to keep it in a database with encrypted. This will give you complete control over the security aspects

Answer (score 0):

Secure your authentication and authorization services using a PKI exchange with a properly signed certificate (so it can be revoked if something does go wrong, and it certainly may).

One example is ws-security (a SOAP extension), but if you need to use REST you're stuck with transport-level security (securing your connection with HTTPS).

You might want to read up at http://security.stackexchange.com for more insightful commentary, rather than "*store it in a property file.*"

Comment: But then you have to store the private key somewhere - basically the same problem.

Comment: If you don't have access to both private keys the public key exchange is moot for all but signature verification.